# cartesian product on two tables

Tags: sql, cartesian-product

I'm trying to create a result set of table names and column names.  In table A I have the list of table names and in Table B I have the list of column names. Each table should have the full list of columns. So:

- Table A

| table_name |
| --- |
| Table1 |
| Table2 |

- Table B

| column_name |
| --- |
| Column1 |
| Column2 |
| Column3 |

The result I want is:

| table_name | column_name |
| --- | --- |
| Table1 | Column1 |
| Table1 | Column2 |
| Table1 | Column3 |
| Table2 | Column1 |
| Table2 | Column2 |
| Table2 | Column3 |

So I have
select

```
select
        table_name
        column_name
from
        A
full outer join
        B
on
        A.TABLE_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME
```

Which gives me:

| table_name | column_name |
| --- | --- |
| Table1 |  |
| Table2 |  |
|  | Column1 |
|  | Column2 |
|  | Column3 |

Close, but no cigar!
How can I get my answer please?

Comment: Without any indication of what result  you're getting versus the result you expect,  there's no way anyone can answer this.  However, table names presumably never match column names, so that ON clause should result in an empty query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
select A.table_name, B.column_name from A, B;
```

Comment: I'd rather suggest using `cross join` instead of this decades old syntax...

Comment: @JamesZ: Because you prefer new verbosity?

Comment: When you have more tables, this can happen by accident -- or you might not realize that it's a cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

try this if your tables are not too big:

```
select
    A.table_name
    , B.column_name
from A
cross join B
```